# Order by clause in inner query with a join

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

```
create table items(item_pk integer, pgid integer, prod_id integer, PRIMARY KEY(item_pk));
create table products(prod_id integer, version  integer, pgid  integer, flag char(1), PRIMARY KEY(prod_id));

insert into items(item_pk,  pgid) values (1,  21);
insert into items(item_pk, pgid) values(2,  31);
insert into products(prod_id, version, pgid, flag) values (11, 101,  21, 'Y');
insert into products(prod_id, version, pgid, flag) values (22, 101,  21, 'N');
insert into products(prod_id, version, pgid, flag) values(33, 101, 31, 'N');

   declare 
    prod_version NUMBER := :1 ;  
    begin  
    update items i set i.prod_id = ( 
     select p.prod_id from products p where 
     p.version = prod_version and p.pgid = i.pgid and rownum =1 
     order by p.flag desc
    ) where i.xyz is null
    commit; end;
```

Products table has two entries - pseudo(flag = 'Y') and actual(flag = 'N').

If there is no pseudo product, need to fetch the actual one.

The above query is resulting in compilation errors. 
The inner query might return more than one record but I just need only the first one(i.e 'Y' record. If 'Y' rec is not found, need 'N' rec).

Comment: @YasinOkumus: The inner query might return two records. And I need 'Y' record if present otherwise need 'N' record.

Comment: I got the point some late, so I deleted my comment sorry. I am writing an answer, I hope I got right this time and you can get the solution. :)

Comment: is "and rownum = 1" an attempt to get only one record?

Answer (score 0):

a bit overkill but should work:

```
select prod_id
from (
    select p.prod_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.flag DESC) as rn
    from products p
    where p.version = prod_version and p.pgid = i.pgid
    )
where rn=1
```

Comment: After reading http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries.php, you might want to add the keyword "distinct" to that query.

Comment: with a condition "rn=1" a distinct is not really required, unless his data requires it. but i have no clue what he has on his table.

Answer (score 0):

You need another select in the update query. I guess it needs to be something like this;

```
update items i set i.prod_id = ( 
  select prod.id from (
    select p.prod_id,rownum rn from products p where 
    p.version = prod_version and p.pgid = i.pgid
  order by p.flag desc) x 
    where x.rn=1
) where i.xyz is null
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not able to recognize "i" in the inner query.

Comment: I cannot try that now but it is odd. Maybe you should consider change the update query as it is written here with innter join of these two tables (items and products): http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any ide available to check my syntax.  I'm doing this from a text editor so there may be bugs.

I always try to avoid using any type of rownum in queries so this may work using a sub-query for the 'N' values.

```
declare 
   prod_version NUMBER := :1 ;  
begin  
  update items i set i.prod_id = (select p.prod_id
                                    from products p
                                   where p.version = prod_version
                                     and p.pgid = i.pgid
                                     and (p.flag = 'Y' 
                                          or (p.flag = 'N' and 0 = (select count(*)
                                                                  from products p2
                                                                 where p2.version = prod_version
                                                                   and p2.pgid = i.pgid
                                                                   and p2.flag = 'Y')
                                              )
                                          )
                                 )
  where i.xyz is null
  commit;
end;
```

However, you could always use plsql and do something like this.

```
declare
  temp_prod_id number;
  prod_version NUMBER := :1 ; 

begin
  for v_rec in (select id, pgid from items where xyz is null) loop
    begin
      select prod_id into temp_prod_id from products p
       where p.version = prod_version
         and p.pgid = v_rec.pgid
         and p.flag = 'Y';
    exception
    when no_data_found then
      select prod_id into temp_prod_id from products p
       where p.version = prod_version
         and p.pgid = v_rec.pgid
         and p.flag = 'N';
  -- this assumes there's always an 'N' record if not wrap this select with exception handling.
    end;

    update items i set i.prod_id = temp_prod_id
    where items.id = v_rec.id;
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

Like I said above, I'm free handing this so double check the syntax.